# Handling <?xml-stylesheet> similar to <link rel="stylesheet">?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, processing-instruction, cssom

During investigation of advantages and disadvantages of attaching CSS with `<?xml-stylesheet>` processing instruction, I came upon some issues.

Suppose we have a simple XHTML document (which is delivered with `application/xhtml+xml` MIME type and viewed in a Web browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>A sample XHTML document</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then we have an external CSS file (let it be named `style.css` and put in root directory):

```css
h1 { color: red; }
```

At first, in `script.js`, I dynamically attach this CSS with a `link` element:

```js
const link = document.createElement('link');
Object.entries({rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/style.css'})
      .forEach(([name, value]) => link.setAttribute(name, value));
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Then the script is waiting until the stylesheet finishes loading and reaches it through `sheet` property:

```js
link.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const stylesheet = link.sheet;
});
```

After this, the script can manipulate this stylesheet, for example:

```js
stylesheet.cssRules.item(0).style.color = 'green';      // modify an existing rule
stylesheet.insertRule('body { background: #ffc; }', 1); // insert a new rule
```

But now, I cannot figure out whether the same manipulations are possible if a stylesheet is attached with `<?xml-stylesheet>` processing instruction:

```js
const pi = document.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet',
           'href="/style.css" type="text/css"');
document.insertBefore(pi, document.documentElement);
```

First, PI seem not to have `load` event, so the script cannot know when the stylesheet is ready. Second, there is nothing like `sheet` property, so you cannot call `pi.sheet` to reach the stylesheet.

Is there any way to overcome these difficulties and to get from the script to the stylesheet associated with `<?xml-stylesheet>` PI?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using processing instruction?

Comment: @guest271314, I am investigating advantages and disadvantages of attaching stylesheets with `<?xml-stylesheet>`.

Comment: _"There aren’t any events for this object, and it doesn’t have any properties for getting its stylesheet."_ Not certain what Question is? Are you trying to get and parse a `StyleSheet` loaded within an `xhtml` `document`? Can you include `xhtml` `document` and what you have tried, and describe requirement at Question?

Comment: I don't think you can "do" anything with processor instructions at all, actually. If you need that level of control over loading of your stylesheet, use a <link>. On the other hand, if all you need is to know when all stylesheets have finished loading, you can use `window.onload`...

Comment: @MrLister, my script inserts `<!xml-stylesheet>` dinamically, long after `window.onload` has fired.

Comment: @Displayname Oh... I didn't even know you could insert processing instructions dynamically. My gut feeling now says, just use an element already.

Comment: @guest271314, I do something like this: `const pi = document.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'href="style.css" type="text/css"'); document.insertBefore(pi, document.documentElement);` Then I want to know when the stylesheet finishes loading and to access this stylesheet from JS. But at the time, I found no way for any of these tasks.

Comment: @Displayname Can you include full `xhtml` and `javascript` at Question to demonstrate what you have tried? What is `document` at `document.createProcessingInstruction()`? Is `document.documentElement` a `ProcessingInstruction` node, or the root node of the `html` portion of `document`? What do you mean by "process this stylesheet from JS"? What needs to be processed? What exactly do you need to process in the `stylesheet`? Why do you not include the processing instruction within the `xhtml` portion of `document`?

Comment: @Displayname Can you include full `xhtm`l and `javascript` at Question to demonstrate what you have tried? What is `document` at `document.createProcessingInstruction()`? Is `document.documentElement` a `ProcessingInstruction` node, or the root node of the `html` portion of `document`? What do you mean by "process this stylesheet from JS"? What exactly do you need to process in the stylesheet?

Comment: @Displayname See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314, I have revised and expanded the question, so there is nothing more to prevent you from giving your competent and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

> First, PI seem not to have load event, so the script cannot know when
>   the stylesheet is ready.

You can use `PerformanceObserver` to check for requested and loaded resources. Iterates nodes of `document`, check for `.nodeType` `7` or `.nodeType` `8`, as `ProcessingInstruction` node could have `comment` `.nodeType`. Get `"resource"` property from performance entries. Parse `.nodeValue` of filtered node for URL at `href="URL"`, check if value is equal to `"resource"` of performance entry, then check if `.styleSheet` `.href` value is equal to parsed URL, and if parsed URL is equal to performance entry `"resource"` property value. If `true`, iterate `.cssRules` or `.rules` of the `styleSheet` loaded at `ProcessingInstruction` node.

```
window.onload = () => {
  let resource;
  const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list, obj) => {
    for (let entry of list.getEntries()) {
      for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(entry.toJSON())) {
        if (key === "name") {
          resource = prop;
          var nodes = document.childNodes;
          _nodes: for (let node of nodes) {
            if (node.nodeType === 7 || node.nodeType === 8 
            && node.nodeValue === pi.nodeValue) {
              let url = node.baseURI 
                        + node.nodeValue.match(/[^href="][a-z0-9/.]+/i)[0];
              if (url === resource) {
                observer.disconnect();
                // use `setTimeout` here for
                // low RAM, busy CPU, many processes running
                let stylesheets = node.rootNode.styleSheets;
                for (let xmlstyle of stylesheets) {
                  if (xmlstyle.href === url && url === resource) {
                    let rules = (xmlstyle["cssRules"] || xmlstyle["rules"]);
                    for (let rule of rules) {
                      // do stuff
                      console.log(rule, rule.cssText, rule.style, xmlstyle);
                      break _nodes;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  observer.observe({
    entryTypes: ["resource"]
  });

  const pi = document.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet',
    'href="style.css" type="text/css"');
  document.insertBefore(pi, document.documentElement);

}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/uXfSzu0dMDCOfZbsdA7n?p=preview

You can also use `MutationObserver`, `setTimeout()` to handle

> low RAM, busy CPU, many processes running

```
window.onload = function() {
  let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log(mutations)
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
      for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
        if (node.nodeName === "xml-stylesheet") {
          let url = node.baseURI 
                    + node.nodeValue.match(/[^href="][a-z0-9/.]+/i)[0];
          setTimeout(function() {
            for (let style of document.styleSheets) {
              if (style.href === url) {
                observer.disconnect();
                // do stuff
                console.log(style)
              }
            }
          // adjust `duration` to compensate for device
          // low RAM, busy CPU, many processes running
          }, 500)  
        }
      }
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true
  });

  const pi = document.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet',
    'href="style.css" type="text/css"');
  document.insertBefore(pi, document.documentElement);

}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/AI4QZiBUx6f1Kmc5qNG9?p=preview

---

Alternatively, use `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` to request `.css` file, create and append `<style>` element to `document`, do stuff with response text, set `.textContent` of `style` element to adjusted `css` text.

Comment: Unfortunately, `PerformanceObserver` can only tell when the resource (e.g. `style.css`) is loaded, i.e. when all its bytes are received by browser engine. But it cannot tell when the new stylesheet is really added to the list of `document.styleSheets` and its properties like `cssRules` are available for scripting.

Comment: On powerful devices, there is no problem. The observer “catches” a loaded CSS file, and it is added to the list so fast that the near-term call of `document.styleSheets` returns the already updated list with a new stylesheet. But testing the code on a device with low capabilities (low RAM, busy CPU, many processes running), I discovered that the stylesheet is not in time for the call of `document.styleSheets`. This call returns the old stylesheets list and cannot find the requested stylesheet in it. Only after a second or two `document.styleSheets` is updated.

Comment: I think the real solution may be to observe `document.styleSheets` directly and to catch events when a new stylesheet is added to it. But I don’t know how to do it (except for using `setInterval`).

Comment: @HydrochoerusHydrochaeris _"But testing the code on a device with low capabilities (low RAM, busy CPU, many processes running), I discovered that the stylesheet is not in time for the call of document.styleSheets"_ You can use `setTimeout()` at either `PerformanceObserver` or `MutationObserver` approach. Adjust `duration` of `setTimeout` to compensate for the specific device.