# Detect ajax requests from raw HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If you get a page's initial HTML, can you detect subsequent ajax requests?

Much like you can in the Developer Console, but programmatically. Have searched extensively for a solution but found none.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PerformanceObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver) with [`entryType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceEntry/entryType) set to `"resource"`

```
function perf_observer(list, observer) { 
   // Process the "resource" event 
} 
var observer2 = new PerformanceObserver(perf_observer); 
observer2.observe({entryTypes: ["resource"]});
```

See

- [Count console.log objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167305/count-console-log-objects/)
- [Handling <?xml-stylesheet> similar to <link rel="stylesheet">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497274/handling-xml-stylesheet-similar-to-link-rel-stylesheet/)

Comment: Where exactly does the HTML go that we are "listening" to?

Comment: @DanL Requirement is to observe all requests from `window`, yes?

Comment: Preferably to observe all requests from a string of HTML not currently loaded into the DOM.

Comment: @DanL What do you mean by  "from a string of HTML"? You can filter all of the requests, for example, by URL. If you know what URL that will be requested. Iterate the key, value pairs of each request, where the URL and initiator of the request is listed when `.getEntries()` is called. You can break the loop i a match is found, the observer will continue to observe all requests until disconnected, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960770/get-actual-image-url-after-redirect/