# How to access requesting URL in network tab listed using any programming language?

Tags: javascript, java, php, python, google-chrome

Suppose there is a website which calls ajax requests everytime however I can't find(or see) any related URL in page source. But I can see every request or ajax calls in network tab using developer tools.

Please refer [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLWyB.png) I attached to find URL in network tab. Let's say `Google analytics` link. How can I search the same URL using javascript or any programming language instead of opening network tab or any developer tool?

I want to see that request URL using programming language. I would prefer javascript if there is. Is it possible or any API available to find the usage of requested links?

I would appreciate if it is possible to get it done using Python, Javascript, Java or PHP.

***HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!***

Comment: You can use `PerfomanceObserver`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406906/detect-ajax-requests-from-raw-html/

Comment: I have gone through your link. but it was not really helpful. Can you please give an example? I was not able to see all the links.

Comment: What do you mean by "not really helpful"? Have you tried the code at the Answer at linked Question?

Comment: I tried. Can you please share working code snippet?

Comment: This one is not working

Comment: Can you describe "not working"? At which browser did you try code? Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: I tried it on chrome using browser console but nothing is being after writing that snippet in console

Comment: @Babaramdev, will you please try out mine snippet same way ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: One option is to use the QT framework and use [WebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html) as well as [QNetworkAccessManager]
(http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to build your own 'network montor'.  QT is available for multiple languages (Python, C++, Lua, Haskell, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser automation tool like Selenium.

Try this python code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("yourwebsiteurl here")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ajax_urls = driver.execute_script("return performance.getEntries().map(entry => entry.name)")

for url in ajax_urls:
    print(url)
```