# How to know the action sent to server by a button on a webpage? do you use a chrome addon for that?

Tags: javascript, html

how do you process to know the action sent to the server by this 'Delete' button on a webpage? do you use a special Chrome addon?

```
<div _ngcontent-geev-pwa-ssr-c1357586839="" class="modal-footer glob-font-body-bold">
  <button _ngcontent-geev-pwa-ssr-c1357586839="" type="button" class="modal-footer-cancel">Dismiss</button>
 ** <button _ngcontent-geev-pwa-ssr-c1357586839="" type="button" class="modal-footer-validate"> Delete </button>**
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

I have used Chrome built-in inspect tool, but this does not provide me any info about the action being actually requested to the web server, what else can I do to find it?

Comment: Check Network tab in DevTools to see if any requests are made when the buttons are clicked. You can also use `PerformanceObserver` to observe network requests, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406906/detect-ajax-requests-from-raw-html/45407041#45407041