# How to intercept all network requests in a web page

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, service-worker

I have a situation in which I need to monitor all network requests made by a web page. When I mean all network requests, I really mean absolutely all of them, that is:

- all requests made from my web page (script or image downloads, XMLHttpRequest requests and so on...)
- all requests made from scripts that have been downloaded from my web page, including scripts from other domains

In this latter case, if I am talking about the following scenario:

```
<!-- Let's say my web page is hosted at https://example.com/ -->
<html>
...
<script src="https://otherdomain.com/somescript.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

If `somescript.js` downloads stuff from the web, from its own domain or any other domain, I need to monitor that, too.

Is that at all possible?

So far, I tried with a service worker, and it does work, at least to some extent. Surprinsgly, some requests are not actually seen by my service worker. Its registration scope is `/`.

Comment: For the most part, scripts from other domains will not be able to make XHR requests to those domains, because they're loaded by a page on your domain. They can however make GET requests for images and other scripts, assuming your content security settings allow it.

Comment: It's possible using `PerformanceObserver` without an extension, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407041/. If you conclude that all requests are not being observed you can use extension API's to monitor all requests, and further log all requests (internally made by the browser and those observable in the browser UI) made to a log file.

Comment: @Pointy thank you. Images are downloaded from an otherdomain.com script, I checked. Do you see any reason why my service worker would not detect these image downloads?

Comment: @guest271314 this is great, however `PerformanceObserver` only reports downloads after the fact, correct? It cannot notify my code about a download being initiated, first, and then, the download being completed, right? What do you mean by extension API's? I'm interested in your approach.

Comment: Web extension API's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions. I've intercepted all requests multiple ways. You might want to look into `debugger`, `webRequest`, `tabs`.

Comment: I can't use browser extensions. This needs to work in a stock browser.

Comment: Then you are going to have to use/exploit `PerformanceObserver` and other related API's. `fetch` event handler in a `ServiceWorker` will help some, too. Sounds like you are not in control of the `WindowClient` though. Are you currently using `fetch` event handler in the `ServiceWorker`?

Comment: Yes I am but, for some reason, while I am receiving fetch events, I am not being notified once the response is ready. I got that thanks to your mechanism based on `PerformanceObserver`, which was a game changer. I need to do more investigations.

Answer (score 0):

You could monkey patch `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` before your target scripts.

An example for `fetch`:

```js
const _fetch = window.fetch;

const prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'fetch');

let events = [];

prop.value = function () {

    console.log('fetch:', ...arguments);
    const out = _fetch.apply(window, arguments);

    out.then(function(response) {

        const _json = response.json;

        response.json = function () {
            const out = _json.call(response);
            out.then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            });
            return out;
        }

        return response;
    });

    return out;

}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'fetch', prop);


fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(r => r.json());
```

Comment: Very nice. Your proposition is also interesting because I get the chance to be notified before and after a download. Will patching both `window.fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` ensure that all (100%) network traffic will go through my custom handlers? Does the browser internally use fetch for Image contents, eg. IMG tags, CSS background-image stuff or Image objects explicitly created through Javascript?

Comment: @andynewman i guess fetch and xml for js only. for resources you can watch them with mutation observer and add onload listener plus maybe service worker