# Detect fetch API request on web page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

**Background:** I am working with the Shopify ScriptTag which allows me to add a JavaScript file on the storefront. All I have is that script file.

**Current Behaviour:** There is an option, "Buy It Now", which allow customers to checkout directly by skipping *Add To Cart*. When they click on *Buy It Now*, Shopify sends a **fetch()** POST request to **checkouts.json** to create the checkout.

**Problem:** I need to detect that this "fetch request happened" in my own JavaScript file.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log("event happened");
});
```

I have tried **Fetch Event API**, but it seems to be only working in **Service Worker** scope.

Is there a possibility to detect this?

Like we can detect **XMLHttpRequest** by overriding its **open** method using prototypal inheritance.

Comment: What do you mean by _"detect"_? The code that you have control over makes the request, correct?

Comment: I don't have control over the behaviour on how the request is being sent. Its happening on the same page, and my script is also there. Can I detect that "request happened"?

Comment: Are there `<iframe>` elements in the HTML `document`? Is the code which makes the request in an `<iframe>` and, or, your code in an `<iframe>` in the HTML `document`?

Comment: Nope. No iframes so far. Its another script file from Shopify ( vendor ) itself which makes this request.

Comment: See [PerformanceObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver/PerformanceObserver);

Comment: Yes. I am currently looking at your solution.

Comment: See stacksnippets and value printed at `console` at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960912/) to the question [Get actual image url after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960770/get-actual-image-url-after-redirect). See also [Handling <?xml-stylesheet> similar to <link rel=“stylesheet”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41497274/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can overwrite `window.fetch` with your own function that calls the original `window.fetch` after (or before) running your own code:

```js
const nativeFetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function(...args) {
  console.log('detected fetch call');
  return nativeFetch.apply(window, args);
}

fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => console.log(text.split('\n')[0]));
```

Comment: Didn't know the spread operator can put arguments into arrays like this, neat.

Answer (score 18):

```js
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
  for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
    if (entry.initiatorType === "fetch") {
      console.log('Fetch request detected to', entry.name);
    }
  }
});

observer.observe({
  entryTypes: ["resource"]
});

fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => console.log(text.split('\n')[0]));
```

Using [Performance Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver). Thanks to @guest271314.

Comment: This answer should be preferred to the currently accepted answer of overwriting `window.fetch`.